# How can I plot relationship between two variables with the constraint of initiating the S-shaped curve from (0,0) as depicted in the example below?

Tags: r, nonlinear

I don't want to run logistic regression or any such regression model. I have 8 to 10 pairs of data points and want to analyze the logistic growth model by fitting any function-generating S-shaped curve like `tanh()` or so on. I am using R for the assigned task.[image]

The blue points in the graph represent the data points and I want to fit the curve as depicted in the graph.

Comment: @BenBolker I tried plotting as you suggested but not yielding expected result, Can you please refer the chart I have attached and suggest something based on it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data sent to me:

```
dd <- structure(list(x=c(18.6,13.13,14.3,5.72,9.1,11.7,7.15 ,4.55, 1.17),
                     y =c( 26.4, 15.28,12.27,10.34,7.7,7.24,6.83,3.47,0.99),
                     class = "data.frame")
)
```

The [Hill function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)) of order 2 (i.e. $y=ax^2/(1+(bx)^2)$) has a sigmoidal shape but goes through $y=0$ when $x=0$. In this parameterization, $a$ is the initial slope and $b$ is the reciprocal of the half-maximum point. Eyeballing the graph for reasonable starting points (an essential step in non-linear fitting), we get $a \approx 0.5$, $b \approx 1/15$.

Fit with `nls()`:

```
fit1 <- nls(y~a*x^2/(1+(b*x)^2), 
             start=list(a=0.5,b=1/15), data=dd)
```

In order to do this without eyeballing every time you either have to (1) trust that the scales are reasonably similar for all of your different data sets or (2) set up a [self-starting function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/selfStart.html) for the `nls` fit.

For this parameterization, the initial slope is $a$, the half-maximum is $1/b$, and the asymptote is $a/b^2$:

```
cc_nls <- as.list(coef(fit1))
res <- with(cc_nls,c(init_slope=a,half_max=1/b,asymptote=a/b^2))
##   init_slope     half_max    asymptote 
##   0.08813282  39.18785991 135.34455071
```

Generate predicted values:

```
xmax <- 100; ymax <- 150     
pframe <- data.frame(x=seq(0,xmax,length=51))
pframe$y <- predict(fit1, newdata=pframe)
```

Construct confidence intervals by the delta method (could also use bootstrapping):

```
vv <- suppressWarnings(emdbook::deltavar(a*pframe$x^2/(1+(b*pframe$x)^2),
                        meanval=coef(fit1),
                        Sigma=vcov(fit1)))
pframe$lwr <- pframe$y-2*sqrt(vv)
pframe$upr <- pframe$y+2*sqrt(vv)
```

Find points where the tangent to the curve is parallel to the linear regression slope (I initially tried to do this analytically, but it gets very ugly ...)

```
cc_lm <- coef(lm(y~x, dd))["x"] ## slope of linear model
dfun <- deriv(expression(a*x^2/(1+(b*x)^2)),"x",
              function.arg=c("x","a","b"))
dfun2 <- function(x) with(cc_nls, 
                       attr(dfun(x,a,b),"gradient")-cc_lm)
u1 <- uniroot(dfun2,c(0,1/cc_nls$b))$root
u2 <- uniroot(dfun2,c(1/cc_nls$b,xmax))$root
```

Plot everything:

```
png("hillfun.png")
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(dd,xlim=c(0,xmax),ylim=c(0,ymax),pch=16,
     xlab="x",ylab="y")
with(pframe,polygon(x=c(x,rev(x)),y=c(lwr,rev(upr)),
                    col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.3)))
abline(lm(y~x, data=dd), lty=2)
abline(v=c(u1,u2),lty=3,col="blue")
abline(h=res["asymptote"],lty=3,col="purple")
with(pframe,lines(x,y,col="red"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: What will be the best way to find the saturation point and critical mass on the curve that you have suggested?

Comment: can you clarify the definition of "saturation point" and "critical mass"?  Do you mean the asymptotic $x$ value (i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty}(y)$) and inflection point respectively? (Do these have anything to do with the vertical segments on your graph?)

Comment: Yes, they are the vertical lines on the graph in question. The points where tangent of S- curve is parallel to the linear fit generated.

Comment: Also, while experimenting with the dd <- structure(list(x=c(18.6,13.13,14.3,5.72,9.1,11.7,7.15 ,4.55, 1.17), (y =c( 26.4,
15.28,12.27,10.34,7.7,7.24,6.83,3.47,0.99)),  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))  The curve goes till infinity and not bending at the top to form a S. @BenBolker

Comment: the coefficients are (a=0.088, b= 0.025), so the half-maximum is at x=1/b=39 and the asymptote is at y=a/b^2 = 135

Comment: Is there any way to make the starting point(a and b) dynamic according to data instead of changing it every time with the change in data? @BenBolker